# How can I install ImageMagick and Imagick latest in a Plesk server

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

I am not a pro at server administration, however, I can install the latest version of ImageMagick 7.1.1 and Imagick 3.7.0 in a server which is not controlled by Plesk.

But, I am using an AWS instance which is controlled by Plesk.

The current version of ImageMagick is 6.9 and Imagick 3.7.0 in my Plesk server.

But, I want to install the latest version of ImageMagick 7.1.1, as some of my website needs the new version.

But, I don't know how to do it in Plesk server.

How can purge/uninstall the current one and How can I install the New one and compile it with PHP?

Is there anyone who can provide me with the full step by step guide and what commands should I run via SSH?

I tried this instruction, but it just didn't work in Plesk Server.

```
sudo apt remove --purge imagemagick
```

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y -qq \
build-essential chrpath debhelper dh-exec dpkg-dev g++ ghostscript gsfonts libbz2-dev \
libdjvulibre-dev libexif-dev libfftw3-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev \
libjpeg-dev liblcms2-dev liblqr-1-0-dev libltdl-dev liblzma-dev libopenexr-dev \
libpango1.0-dev libperl-dev libpng-dev librsvg2-bin librsvg2-dev libtiff-dev libwebp-dev \
libwmf-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxml2-dev libxt-dev pkg-config pkg-kde-tools zlib1g-dev
```

```
git clone https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.git ImageMagick-7.1.1
cd ImageMagick-7.1.1
./configure --with-rsvg --with-modules
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

```
git clone https://github.com/Imagick/imagick
cd imagick
phpize && ./configure
make
make install
```

I have also added **extension=imagick.so** into my php.ini

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]. SO is only for _programming_ questions.